# Keras accuracy not affected by any change in model

Tags: accuracy, loss-functions, multi-class, keras

I am trying to construct a model for single-label multiclass classification using Keras in a Jupyter notebook. Here's my model (or see [full jupyter notebook](https://github.com/joelberkeley/ml-sandbox/blob/master/olympics/main.ipynb)):

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', input_dim=9))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

I'm getting training accuracy of 0.8538, a validation accuracy of 0.8533, and a test accuracy of 0.8524. However, these values don't change for any of the following:

- adding/removing hidden layers
- increasing or decreasing the width of each layer (even to 1)
- changing the optimizer to adam
- changing softmax to sigmoid (!)
- changing batch_size
- validation_split of 0.1 and 0.2

Also, these values are reached within 1 epoch and don't budge from there. My losses do similar at ~0.57. I'd expect after a lot of epochs to see some level of overfitting, but I'm just getting training and validation loss flat-lining at slightly different values.

I've tried

- normalising the data
- filling missing values

I feel there must be something seriously broken with my workflow but can't for the life of me figure out what.

**EDITS**

- there are 271116 data points, 1/3 of which are used as test data
- as per Sycorax's suggestion, I reduced learning rate. This just slowed the process of arriving at the same values

Comment: Do you have 4 labels?

Comment: @GermánAlfaro i believe so. initially as string, then formatted as integer, then to categorical (samples, 4) tensor

Comment: Is the loss decreasing?

Comment: only from epoch 1 to 2: 0.8073 to 0.5768 (and 0.5784 to 0.5783 for validation)

Comment: I notice that you haven't tried adjusting the learning rate. I suspect that could be the issue.

Comment: How many training examples? It's also possible that your input variables are just not that informative.

Comment: @DezmondGoff see question edit - 271116 * 0.67 * 0.8 training samples

Comment: @Sycorax see edit